# Replacement for Check Constraint that refers to other rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am under the impression that CHECK() constraints may only reference values within the same row in question.  I am trying to figure out, then how, I can enforce the following rule:

Given the Following Table:

```
PK_Employee_ID | Employee_Name | Manager_ID
```

Where Manager ID is the ID of another Employee on the Table.  I need a rule where, if a given row's PK_Employee_ID has been referenced in another row's Manager_ID, it's own Manager_ID must be null.  That is:

Not every employee needs to have a manager, but
an employee who is the manager of another employee may not, in turn, have a manager.

I know that there are other ways to solve the problem; there could be another bit column that is simply "Is_Manager", which, if 1, means that Manager_ID must be null. However, I would prefer the more elegant solution of, rather than explicitly telling each row whether or not they are a manager, let them figure it out for themselves by looking at the other rows.  This would make it much easier to change the relationship between given rows.  Or, is this simple a terribly inefficient way to handle the problem?

Comment: You might consider using a trigger?

Comment: I hate triggers, but this is the one case where they're most helpful; enforcing referential integrity.

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit more on why you don't like them?  are they just difficult to work with, or do they perform slowly?  what would you do?

Comment: A lot of people don't like triggers because they are easy to forget (thus giving 'unexpected' results), and hard to debug, and cause performance issues if badly written. You probably shouldn't use them for any heavy business logic, but for relatively simple data validation like this, I would go ahead and build a trigger for insert and update to do your checks.

Comment: Thanks for the Information!  I'll look into it more.